# How to insert a dot after the theorem environment?

Tags: theorems, punctuation

How to insert a dot after the theorem environment?
I use `\newtheorem{exerc}{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{exerc}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{exerc}
 Exercise
\end{exerc}
\end{document}
```

I need.

1. Exercise
2. Exercise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
\renewcommand{\theexerc}{\arabic{exerc}.}% #.
```

just after you declare your new theorem `\newtheorem{exerc}{}`.

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to touch `\theexerc` for that sort of thing as it will also affects the `\label`/`\ref` mechanism. Using `\theoremseparator{.}` from the ntheorem package (which is an expansion of the theorem package) will avoid any side effect.

Answer (score 14):

I usually use `amsthm` instead of `theorem`.  It provides `\newtheoremstyle` in which you can define your own theorem styles:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
% the following style is based on the example
% found in the amsthm manual
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
{3pt}% space above
{3pt}% space below
{}% body font
{}% indent amount
{}% theorem head font
{.}% punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% space after theorem head
{}% theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{exerc}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{exerc}
Exercise
\end{exerc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope it helps. `=)`

Answer (score 6):

Below is a solution using `ntheorem`. As a side note, if you're making Exercises/Problems with associated solutions, you might like to look up the `answers` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremprework{}
\theorempostwork{}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{exerc}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{exerc}
 Exercise
\end{exerc}

\end{document}
```